# Create a polyline from a KML file

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-polyline

I have a map on my website and I'd like to make some paths on it from kml files. I found [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml/), and I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geoXml = null;
var map = null;
var myLatLng = null;

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        //stuff
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

      geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                      map: map
                  });
      geoXml.parse('paths/path1.kml');
    };
</script>
```

It's from the documentation sample. Now I want to retrieve the path by accessing some property of `geoXml`, but my browser's debugger claims it's undefined, even though the markers that define the points of the polyline from the kml file show up on the map. How do do draw a path from a file, not necessarily using this method?

Here's the file:
http://pastebin.com/R1PsuumL
I want to create the path  from the coords in `Folder/Placemark/LineString/coordinates`.

Comment: Could you please show us the script tag where you load geoxml?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a Polyline from a KML file that contains only Placemarks containing only "Point" geometries?

Comment: A link to a map or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem would be helpful (and/or perhaps a sample KML file).

Comment: Added geoxml loading line and kml file fragment.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=23.364511&lng=28.433372&zoom=21&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlproxy060215.asp?http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=r1psuuml) is your KML rendered with geoxml3.